# Pytest is not showing test results, only says that it collected tests?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pytest, qt-designer

I am working on some unit tests for my python code and for the test I wrote, pytest is only collecting the tests but not showing if the tests are passed or failed.

I just did a fresh install of pytest, if that makes a difference.

**sos_game.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QSpinBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic
from board import Ui_MainWindow
import sys



class SOSGame(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Connect the valueChanged signal of the spin box to the setSize method.
        self.ui.spinBox.setValue(3)
        self.ui.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.setSize)
        
        # default game mode
        self.ui.radioButton.setChecked(True)
        
        # Blue Player default settings
        self.ui.radioButton_7.setChecked(True)
        self.ui.radioButton_8.setChecked(True)
        
        # Red Player default settings
        self.ui.radioButton_3.setChecked(True)
        self.ui.radioButton_5.setChecked(True)

        
        # setting the buttons to the type of game mode
        self.ui.radioButton.toggled.connect(lambda: self.setGameMode("Simple"))
        self.ui.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(lambda: self.setGameMode("General"))
        
        # Create the initial game board.
        self.boardSize = self.ui.spinBox.value()
        self.createBoard()
        
      

    def createBoard(self):
        # Clear the existing game board.
        if hasattr(self, 'board'):
            self.board.deleteLater()  
            self.ui.gridLayout.removeWidget(self.board)

        # Create a new game board with the specified size.
        self.board = QWidget()
        boardLayout = QGridLayout()
        
        # Set the initial player to blue
        self.currentPlayer = "blue"
        
        for row in range(self.boardSize):
            for col in range(self.boardSize):
                button = QPushButton()
                button.setMaximumSize(150, 150)
                boardLayout.addWidget(button, row, col)
                
                # Connect the clicked signal of the button to the buttonClicked function.
                button.clicked.connect(lambda _, r=row, c=col: self.buttonClicked(r, c))
                
        self.board.setLayout(boardLayout)
        self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.board)
        
        
        
    
    def buttonClicked(self, row, col):
        # Get the clicked button.
        button = self.board.layout().itemAtPosition(row, col).widget()
        # Set the mark for the current player.
        mark = "S" if self.currentPlayer == "blue" else "O"
        button.setText(mark)
        # Switch to the other player.
        self.currentPlayer = "red" if self.currentPlayer == "blue" else "blue"
        




    def setSize(self, size):
        # Update the size of the game board.
        self.boardSize = size
        self.createBoard()
        
        
             
    def setGameMode(self, mode):
     self.gameMode = mode
     
    
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    game = SOSGame()
    game.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test_sos_game.py**

```
from sos_game import SOSGame

def test_create_board():
    game = SOSGame()
    game.createBoard()
    assert game.board is not None
    assert game.board.layout().count() == game.boardSize ** 2
    
def test_button_clicked():
    game = SOSGame()
    game.createBoard()
    button = game.board.layout().itemAtPosition(0, 0).widget()
    game.currentPlayer = "blue"
    game.buttonClicked(0, 0)
    assert button.text() == "S"
    assert game.currentPlayer == "red"
    
def test_set_size():
    game = SOSGame()
    game.setSize(4)
    assert game.boardSize == 4
    game.createBoard()
    assert game.board.layout().count() == game.boardSize ** 2
    
def test_set_game_mode():
    game = SOSGame()
    game.setGameMode("Simple")
    assert game.gameMode == "Simple"
```

Here is the result that I got in the terminal.
[image: pytest results]

Comment: How did you invoke pytest?

Comment: @HaiVu typing pytest in the terminal through vscode, it also says that the test session starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this option **pytest -vv**

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a @pytest.fixture and a app function so that the test function can use the sos_game file and test the functions

```
import pytest
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
import sos_game

@pytest.fixture
def app(qtbot):
    test_sos = sos_game.SOSGame()  # replace MyWidget with your widget class name
    qtbot.addWidget(test_sos)
    
    return test_sos
    
    
def test_create_board(app):
        game = app            # changed this line
        game.createBoard()
        assert game.board is not None
        assert game.board.layout().count() == game.boardSize ** 2
```

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to your question.